# Handle the case if an employee have more than one allowance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to write a simple query that calculates the total salary and I have a problem that if an employee have more than allowance it will show him twice.

This is what I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    employee.ename, Dept.Dname
    , (Employee.Salary + ISNULL(allownces.amount,0)-ISNULL(deduction.amount,0)) AS total_salary
    , allownces.amount AS allow, deduction.amount AS ded    
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Dept ON Dept.id = Employee.dept_id
LEFT JOIN allownces ON allownces.emp_id = Employee.id
LEFT JOIN deduction ON deduction.emp_id = Employee.id
GROUP BY ename, Dname, Salary, allownces.amount, deduction.amount
```

and the result it will calculate the total salary of an employee if he have 2 allowance then it will calculate it two times and I want to calculate the allowance if he have more than one and show it as one.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` when you have no aggregation?

Comment: I want to Group By ename but I can't it won't let me until I write all of them

Comment: But grouping, without aggregation, is pointless. You're better off using `DISTINCT` if you want distinct groups with no aggregation.

Comment: I highly recommend using (short) table aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with outer apply instead of left join.

```
SELECT 
    employee.ename, Dept.Dname, (Employee.Salary + ISNULL(a.amount,0)-ISNULL(d.amount,0)) AS total_salary
    , allownces.amount AS allow, deduction.amount AS ded    
FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Dept ON Dept.id = Employee.dept_id
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT sum(amount) amount
    FROM allownces
    WHERE allownces.emp_id = Employee.id
) a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT sum(amount) amount
    FROM deduction
    WHERE deduction.emp_id = Employee.id
) d
```